# Java program to count characters, words, and lines from a text file

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that gathers statistics on a text file in a way that is similar to word processors which tell you how many characters, words, and lines you have written.

The purpose of this program is to ask the user for the name of a file (**using a scanner**) and output the statistics.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class DocStats {
private File inputFile;
private Scanner in;

// Sets users input (string attribute) to a file name
public DocStats(String string) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        File inputFile = new File(string);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

        this.inputFile = inputFile;
        this.in = in;
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Could not open the file");
    }
}

// Gets the number of characters in a text
public int getNumberOfCharacters() {
    int numChar = 0;

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        numChar += line.length();
    }

    return numChar;
}

// Gets the number of words in a text
public int getNumberOfWords() {
    int numWords = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        numWords += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
    }

    return numWords;
}

// Gets the number of lines in a text
public int getNumberOfLines() {
    int numLines = 0;
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        numLines++;
    }
    return numLines;
}
}
```

After I test my class in the main method, I do not get correct outputs. Here is the main method:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    DocStats doc = new DocStats("goblin.txt");

    System.out.println("Number of characters: "
            + doc.getNumberOfCharacters()); // outputs 1402, instead of 1450

    System.out.println("Number of words: " + doc.getNumberOfWords()); // outputs
                                                                        // 0
                                                                        // instead
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // 257
    System.out.println("Number of lines: " + doc.getNumberOfLines()); // outputs
                                                                        // 0
                                                                        // instead
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // 49
}
}
```

Could anyone point out why my code does not work and suggest any alternative way to fix it?

Comment: In one place you do `hasNext` with `next`. In another, you use `hasNext` with `nextLine`. In another even, you just use `hasNext`. Do you know what those do?

Answer (score 0):

You are scanning the file in the getNumberOfCharacters() method, and that is why it is non-zero.  The others are 0 since the scanner is at the end of the file.

You need to change your DocStats class to have only one loop

```
in = new Scanner(file);
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
  // count the lines
  lines++;
  String line = in.nextLine();

  // chars in the line, plus one for the newline
  chars  += line.length() + 1;

  // count words.  Are there other word terminators, such as . ? ! -
  words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
}
```

Comment: I have tried to run your code, however, I still get wrong values. In my .txt file, the last line does not have '\n', meaning I cannot use                       chars  += line.length() + 1;                                                                                   At the same time, I still get 0 for number of words and number of lines. And the last thing, I do have elements such as . ? ! - in my text

Answer (score -2):

So what you need to do is eliminate all the while loops besides the one in public DocStats()

in public DocStats you put the while loop Clayton Wilkinson created.

```
public int getNumberOfCharacters() {

        return characterCount;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @return wordCount
     * 
     */

    public int getNumberOfWords() {

        return wordCount;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @return lineCount
     * 
     */

    public int getNumberOfLines() {

        return lineCount;

    }
```